# CRC Failed, File is broken, using php system command to tar a directory

Tags: linux, unix, tar, gzip, compression

Can anybody see a problem with the below PHP code? Or have any ideas to troubleshoot a solution as to why whenever I download the backup file.tar.gz and try to open it using 7zip on windows... that I keep being told ***CRC failed, file is broken***?

```
system("tar -cvzwf ".escapeshellarg($backup_file_location)." ".escapeshellarg($folder_to_backup));
```

I am taring my public_html directory to a backup folder that is beneath that directory (not accessible via the web).

Everything seems to flow smoothly but upon opening the files I keep getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have the `-w` option in your `tar` command? It means "Interactive mode, ask for confirmation for everything". This likely causes the error.

Comment: **-cvzf** still produces the same error

Comment: -cvzf still produces the error because I was downloading the tar.gz file using FTP type ASCII instead of auto/binary. Hopefully these few keywords will help somebody find the solution to their problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a printout of the resulting command and check it directly in a console.
(be sure to use the same user as http server)